# «Ништо» или таки «нешто»?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, смысл, разговорная-речь

Если разница между *нешто* и *ништо*? Викисловарь говорит, что нету.
Я на *ништо* в справочнике РАН наткнулся. Оба ли-с варианта правильны?

`Ништо/Нешто он и вправду тебе целый жёлтый подсолнух подарил-таки?!`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Выбираю на основе примеров из ответа **@Буратино**

Умели-таки раньше выразить **иронию очень эмоционально)**

(1) ***Не́што** он и вправду тебе целый жёлтый подсолнух подарил-таки?! Как-то на него не похоже.*

(2) ***Ни́што** он и вправду тебе целый жёлтый подсолнух подарил-таки?! Сочиняешь, поди!  **Ни́што** сама выпросила!*

(3) ***Ништо́**, он всем такие подсолнухи дарит.*

***Ништо́** тебе, думала, поди, что еще что подарит.*

Answer (score 2):

Конечно же, между *не́што* (или *ни́што*) и *ништо́* разница есть. Тут надо следить за ударением, которое меняет значение разговорного слова.
В этом предложении правильно использовать частицу ***не́што*** (или ***ни́што***):

*Не́што* [ни́што] *он и вправду тебе целый жёлтый подсолнух подарил-таки?!*

[**Не́што**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/197220/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%82%D0%BE) (*част. разг.-сниж.*) — употребляется при ответе на сообщение, которое вызывает удивление, изумление, недоверие или неудовлетворение, соответствуя по значению сл.: *так ли, правда ли, возможно ли, **неужели***;
синонимы: неужели, неужли, неужто, **ни́што**, разве.

Примеры:
***Не́што** он мог без моего согласия брать?* (А. П. Чехов. Беззащитное существо);
*— Ну вот, пошла баба голосить! уйми ты ее, Иван! — обратился старик к старшему сыну, — **не́што** лучше бы было, кабы не отпустило сына-то...* (М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Святочный рассказ);
***Ни́што** ж не притянул Вихорь красного к казакам?* (М. А. Шолохов. Тихий Дон).

> А тихие дети окружили Егорку и Гришу, в широкий стали круг и увлекли их в легком круговом движении хоровода.
> — Государи мои ангелы, — вскрикивал Егорка, кружась и ликуя, — личики ваши светленькие, оченьки ваши ясненькие, рученьки ваши беленькие, ноженьки ваши легонькие! **Ни́што** я на земле, **ни́што** я в раю? Голубчики, братики и сестрицы, где же ваши крылышки?
> (Ф. К. Сологуб. Капли крови)

Answer (score 2):

Есть слова **что** и **што**. **Что** - это указание на вещь, что-то, чего-либо.

**Што** - это вопрос общего характера, без конкретизации на предмете или вещи, про идеи или понятия.

**Нечто** - то, что не похоже на что-то из предлагаемого ряда вещей. Нечто иное - возьми что-то другое. Не чего-то, но иное что-то.

**Ни что** - ничего из, отрицание того, что есть. Ни что из этого не подходит.

**Ништо** - связано с немецким нихт/нихил, не существование вообще: этого и другого, иного, вещественного и невещественного, отрицание идеи - нигилизм.

Из "**ни что**" можно сделать **ничтожество**, из **ништо** ничего другого сделать не получится.

**Нешто** - несильное отрицание, легкое сомнение, либо даже согласие, указание на то, неужели, правда ли, может ли быть. Но предположение о другой идее. Ты не прав, но есть идея... Используется для утверждения.

**Ни́што** - скорее отрицание идеи. Сильное недоверие к сказанному, часто с контраргументом. Используется для усиления связанного отрицания, либо для противного высказывания, протеста. Ни за что, это не правильно.

> О, откупы, святые откупы! Какую вы приносите государству пользу! А вы, проклятые науки, лишь только его разоряете! Ништо вам, ученые люди, что дети ваши после вас по миру таскаются. Сумароков.

Ништо вам, ученые люди, что... - Верно безразлично вам, что ваши дети по миру таскаются. Одним "неужели" тут не обойтись, так как "ваши дети таскаются" - это уже не утверждение, а выражение протеста. Усиление протеста.

> Аксен (плачет, лежа на полу) Ох, о-ох, косточки все переломал. Вот тебе блинки твои. Ништо, еще не то будет. Фонвизин.

Ништо, еще не то будет - двойное отрицание, не верь это не конец, по сравнению с тем что будет это ништо, пустое, пустяк. Опровержение того что есть и усиление.

> Да извольте прежде спросить, что за собака; это дворникова нашего дворная сука. Время пришло, вскочила в карету да и ощенилась. Ее и черт оттуда не выживет, ништо сама выйдет.

Чёрт - это что-то, сущность, но она выйдет только через ништо, сама собой, без воздействия чего-то или кого-то. Усиление отрицания.

Сравним с нешто:

> Нешто, брат, ты, Анюта, заспесивела ныньче: бывало, так и Матвей бывал миленьким дружком. П. А. Плавильщиков. Бобыль.

Нет отрицания, все наоборот так хорошо, что не верится.

> ..да такие-то нешто все богатые, да добрые, да великодушные... Погодин.

Тоже - неужели, не могу поверить.

> ...нешто добрались; а и белые калачи их ладно под зуб ложатся, батюшка, что у нас вот пирогами зовут. Даль.

> Нешто хочешь ты их откапывать из земли? Гоголь.

Неужто, может ли быть, что, правда ли.

А теперь опять ништо:

> Такъ я васъ насильно втащу... сказала она рѣшительно и начала, выбиваясь ихъ силъ, тащить Савелья Ѳомича. — Эка шалунья! экой вѣтеръ! говорилъ онъ, карабкаясь на окно: — ну, погоди, погоди, я самъ влѣзу. Вмигъ онъ очутился въ комнатѣ и въ объятіяхъ помиравшей со смѣху Лизы. — Ништо вамъ, папочка! говорила она: — это вамъ за то, чтобъ вы впередъ не подсматривали за своей цыпкой. И она снова стала хохотать, какъ сумасшедшая. Достоевский.

Ништо вам, папочка - то-то, поделом вам, будите знать, раз не знали. Совсем не вяжется с "неужели".

Хотя в дальнейшем **ништо** наравне с **нешто** начинает употребляться в выражениях "*ништо ты*", "*ништо ему*" и тп., и именно в этих выражениях в целом, вероятно, сравнивается по значению.

Comment: Класс! При объяснении семантики слов вам равных просто нет.